# Solar Cycle UV Variation

Tags: astronomy, radiation, sun

The average energy we receive from the Sun is $1,366 \ \mathrm{W/m^2}$ , and this only varies by $0.1\%$ from the activity peak to trough of its 11 year cycle. About $9\%$ of the energy comes from wavelengths less than $400 \ \mathrm{nm}$. The $200-300\ \mathrm{nm}$ region varies on the order of a few percent, $150-200 \ \mathrm{nm}$ by $10-20\%$ and shorter regions by over $50\%$ with maximums at the cycles peak activity. Energy above $400 \ \mathrm{nm}$ is almost constant over the cycle. Why does solar energy variation over the Sun's activity cycle vary inversely with wavelength?
http://astro.ic.ac.uk/research/solar-irradiance-variation

Answer (score 1):

This must be due to the fact, that majority of visible spectra is emitted by whole sun surface, which have stable size & temperature.

While short-wave UV must be emitted by hotspots & bursts, number & size of which is not constant and varies in large range.

Comment: BarsMonster: Plages dominate sunspots during solar max increasing UV, and the corona is more energetic during solar max increasing EUV and x-rays. Is that consistent with your idea?